# Can I use client certificate ONLY for authentication in Postgresql?

Tags: performance, postgresql, ssl

To sum it up: I would like to have the security benefit of authentication on client cert, but don't want to pay the cost of encryption (and in Postgresql's case, compression) for the rest of the session.

In my pg_hba.conf on the server, for testing, I only have this:

```
hostssl all         testuser   0.0.0.0/0             cert
```

On the client side, I have "sslmode={require,allow,...} options working already with psql. But I am looking at the "sslmode" option in the document and really wish there is one sslmode option called "require_only_for_authentication", but I can't find it.

Anyone knows a way to skip SSL encryption after authenticating with client cert in the same connection session?

Any suggestions will be appreciated!